# Read PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer classpath Spring with Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss

Using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to externalize spring-configuration 
properties.

Added following code to `spring-servlet.xml`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="location">
         <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
     </property>
  </bean>
```

Filter to be externalized from `spring-security.xml`

```
<security:custom-filter position="AUTH_FILTER" ref="${filter}" />
```

`filter` value is present in  `environment.properties`

`environment.properties` file is present inside Jboss modules and is readable from code using resource bundle.

But, with these changes somehow properties file is not getting loaded and following error is thrown while publishing code.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'filter' in string value "${filter}"

PS:

Also tried hardcoding path as `<value>file:${jboss.home.dir}/modules/system/layers/base/configuration/main/environment.properties</value>` but, dosen't seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your `spring-servlet.xml` is not linked to your `spring-security.xml`. So `spring-security.xml` has no knowledged of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

IMO, you should configure `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in a `properties-context.xml` (for instance) so you can `import` this new file into your `spring-servlet.xml` and `spring-security.xml` as following:

```
<import resource="classpath:properties-context.xml" />
```